# Two classes in :not() selector

Tags: html, css

I want to have certain styles applied to an element, when it does not have two classes (not either of the two classes, but both of the two classes).
The `:not` selector does not seem to accept two classes. Using two seperate `:not` selectors causes it to be interpreted as an OR statement. I need the styles to be applied when it is does

```css
p:not(.foo.bar) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<p class="foo">This is a (.foo) paragraph.</p>
<p class="bar">This is a (.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p class="foo bar">This is a (.foo.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a normal paragraph.</p>
```

So any element with the class `foo` should have the styles applied to it, as well as any element with the class `bar`. Only if an element has both classes (`class="foo bar"`), the styles should not be applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:not` pseudo class takes a simple selector, so use i.e. the attribute selector

```css
p:not([class="foo bar"]) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<p class="foo">This is a (.foo) paragraph.</p>
<p class="bar">This is a (.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p class="foo bar">This is a (.foo.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a normal paragraph.</p>
```

---

Update based on a comment

If the order of the classes can alter, do like this

```css
p:not([class="bar foo"]):not([class="foo bar"]) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<p class="foo">This is a (.foo) paragraph.</p>
<p class="bar">This is a (.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p class="foo bar">This is a (.foo.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a normal paragraph.</p>
<p class="bar foo">This is a (.bar.foo) paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Maybe you could copy OP's Stack Snippet with your CSS into your answer so we can see this in action, too. :)

Comment: @domdom Just did :)

Comment: Cheers! For me, all but the third paragraph show in red, however.

Comment: @domdom Exactly as it was asked for :)

Comment: Ah, indeed! I actually understood it the other way round. Nice solution then. Just one drawback: it only works if you note the classes in the selector in the *same order* as in the markup, right? Or you need to note down all possible permutations.

Comment: @domdom Updated my answer if so is the case

Answer (score 0):

```css
p:not(.foo):not(.bar) {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<p class="foo">This is a (.foo) paragraph.</p>
<p class="bar">This is a (.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p class="foo bar">This is a (.foo.bar) paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a normal paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: ***Using two seperate :not selectors causes it to be interpreted as an OR statement.*** read question carefully

Comment: @LGSon Okay I got  OP's requirement, I think he wanted which i posted.