# Selector for element having one of two classes, but not both

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select elements having one of two classes, but not both?

I tried `:not(.class1, .class2)` and `:not(.class1):not(.class2)` but they seem to select elements missing either class. I need to select elements that don't have **both** classes.

I also tried `:not([class='class1 class2'])` [as this accepted answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696263/2560938), but it doesn't seem to select anything.

Here is a sample of what I want -

```css
ul.tabs > li.active:not([class='first last']) {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="first">1st</li>
    <li class="active last">2nd</li> <!-- Should be red -->
</ul>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active first last">1st</li> <!-- Should NOT be red -->
</ul>
```

The `<li>`'s have other classes I'm not responsible over. I'm wondering if there is a way of *ignoring* other classes for the last selector I tried.

Comment: :not(.class1):not(.class2) works perfectly

Comment: `:not(.class1):not(.class2)` doesn't work. It selects element missing **at least** one class, not both. Meaning in the first example the 2nd tab is not red. Why the downvotes?

Comment: I don't think css `:not()` works here https://jsfiddle.net/d9bk9m04/

Comment: I don't know, I didn't downvote, but now I'm a little confused. That li.active.last isn't missing both classes - since it does have the "last" class. As stated, :not(.first):not(.last) will match elements that don't have either class. But that's simply not what you're looking for.

Comment: @BoltClock I want the <li> to be red whenever it has the class **active** and not both **first** and **last**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `:not(.first), :not(.last)` which is the Selectors level 3-supported version of `:not(.first.last)` (from Selectors 4, not yet supported by all browsers, as well as jQuery):

```css
ul.tabs > li.active:not(.first), ul.tabs > li.active:not(.last) {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="first">1st</li>
    <li class="active last">2nd</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active first last">1st</li>
</ul>
```

As Rounin points out, though, you should be able to just use `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`, or `:first-child` and `:last-child`, instead of bloating the markup with with "first" and "last" classes (if those classes represent the same things as the pseudo-classes).

In fact, if you do switch to those pseudo-classes, you can simplify your CSS to just one selector by condensing `:not(:first-of-type), :not(:last-of-type)` to `:not(:only-of-type)`:

```css
ul.tabs > li.active:not(:only-of-type) {
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>1st</li>
    <li class="active">2nd</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active">1st</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, you can use two CSS pseudo-classes:

- `:first-of-type`
- `:last-of-type`

and take advantage of the CSS cascade, by declaring the rule for `:first-of-type` beneath the rule for `:last-of-type`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.tabs li:last-of-type.active {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
.tabs li:first-of-type.active {background-color: transparent;}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
<li>1st</li>
<li class="active">2nd</li> <!-- Should be red -->
</ul>

<ul class="tabs">
<li class="active">1st</li> <!-- Should NOT be red -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to use a CSS selector to select html elements with either one of two classes, but not both of the classes

**Or how to do XOR in a CSS selector**

What you need is [XOR - Exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Exclusive or is a logical operation that is true **if and only if its arguments differ** (one is true, the other is false).

#### XOR

| Input A | Input B | Outcome Q |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Unfortunately there's not an XOR operator in CSS which makes this a bit tricky.
But we have both AND ant NOT, and those two together gets us NAND (NOT AND).
The cool thing with NAND is that it is possible to [combine NAND to express any Boolean expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic)!

So we need XOR which can be realized with NAND like this

[image: XOR realized by combining NAND]

XOR = ( A NAND ( A NAND B ) ) NAND ( B NAND ( A NAND B ) )

So lets say A = the CSS class first, and B = the CSS class last, then we get this:

```css
li.active:not(:not(.first:not(.first.last)):not(.last:not(.first.last)))
{
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="first">1st</li>
    <li class="active last">2nd</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active first last">1st</li>
</ul>
```

Lets break it down

1. In CSS AND is realized by chaining two selectors together, so in order to get CSS version of `first NAND last` we do `:not(.first.last)`
2. Next we need `( first NAND ( first NAND last ) )` which we get with `:not(.first:not(.first.last))`, again chaining together `first` with the expression `:not(.first.last)` from point 1 above. This gives us the left part of the complete expression.
3. The second and right part of the expression is almost identical to the left part

   | Part | Expression |
   | --- | --- |
   | Left | ( A NAND ( A NAND B ) ) |
   | Right | ( B NAND ( A NAND B ) ) |

   So all we need to to is to swap out the first A for B, or in our case, swap out the first `first` for `last`, and that should give us the right and last half of the expression, `:not(.last:not(.first.last))`
4. All we now need to do it to AND those two parts together and then negate them with a NOT.
   So again we do AND by chaining the two parts together which result in `:not(.first:not(.first.last)):not(.last:not(.first.last))`.
   And then we add the final NOT to get `not(:not(.first:not(.first.last)):not(.last:not(.first.last)))`.
   And that's the complet XOR expression realized with NAND (NOT and AND).
5. The final step is to limit the entire XOR-expression to only li-tags with the class active.
   So we chain it together with a basic tag+class selector and we get the final result: `li.active:not(:not(.first:not(.first.last)):not(.last:not(.first.last)))`

Comment: Great breakdown. Selectors 4 now also introduces :is(), effectively an OR operator that doesn't require duplicating the rest of the selector. As "A XOR B" can also be expressed as "(A OR B) AND (NOT (A AND B))" the selector can therefore be simplified to `li.active:is(.first, .last):not(.first.last)`, removing the need for any NANDs. I don't know of any Selectors 3-compatible solution that's simpler than the one I answered with, though level 4 :not() and :is() are reasonably well-supported at this point.